# Find Matching record in MongoDB with one record from array

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of contacts and I need to find one or more contacts that match records from an array.

The array looks like this:

```
[
    { linkType: "email", "bob@example.com" },
    { linkType: "email", "joan@example.com" }
    { linkType: "customerID", "12345" }
]
```

The contact record ( cut down ) looks like this:

```
{
    "code": "cust01",
    "contactLink": [
        {
            "linkType": "email",
            "value": "joe@example.com"
        },
        {
            "linkType": "customerID",
            "value": "12345"
        }
    ],
    "name": "joe bloggs"
}
```

I only need one match from the array - but both fields need to match , the result could return multiple records. How can I do this without doing multiple finds ( iterating the array ) ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

We can use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to apply filter on array elements. The following is an example:

```
db.collection.find({
    "contactLink":{
        $elemMatch:{
            "linkType": "email",
            "value": "joe@example.com"
        }
    }
}).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d89b84c9c5291d5f4963e7d"),
    "code" : "cust01",
    "contactLink" : [
        {
            "linkType" : "email",
            "value" : "joe@example.com"
        },
        {
            "linkType" : "customerID",
            "value" : "12345"
        }
    ],
    "name" : "joe bloggs"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d89b84c9c5291d5f4963e7e"),
    "code" : "cust01",
    "contactLink" : [
        {
            "linkType" : "email",
            "value" : "josh@example.com"
        },
        {
            "linkType" : "customerID",
            "value" : "12345"
        }
    ],
    "name" : "joe bloggs"
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d89b84c9c5291d5f4963e7d"),
    "code" : "cust01",
    "contactLink" : [
        {
            "linkType" : "email",
            "value" : "joe@example.com"
        },
        {
            "linkType" : "customerID",
            "value" : "12345"
        }
    ],
    "name" : "joe bloggs"
}
```